# Linux add string to a command output before the output is saved into a file

Tags: linux

```
$ ps -p 31690 -o %cpu,%mem
%CPU %MEM
80.3  0.0
```

Given the above result, I would like to have a csv, like this:

> aaa,80.3,0.0

while used in a shell script like this:

```
for i in { 1..31 }
do
  aaa=$i
  // call ps and write result to a csv
done
```

Comment: What you are asking is very unclear. Are you asking how to repeat a PS command 31 times outputting it as a CSV and including the iteration number as the first value per entry?

Comment: @davidgo I run a process 31 times, and I need to record the CPU and MEM into a CSV file. I know how to make a loop in shell, but not sure about manipulate the stdout and stdin. Now I know the right tool is AWK :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for aaa in {1..31} ;do
  echo $aaa$(ps --no-headers -p "$aaa" -o %cpu,%mem | tr -s ' ' ',') #>>/tmp/output.csv
done
```

Comment: This won't quite work as stands  I believe you have an error after the -p - $aaa is not the process ID its the sequence number - so it needs to be replaced with the PID   Also the "#" near the end of the second last line means output is never written to stdout.

Comment: @davidgo I finally solved this by `ps -p $pid -o %cpu,%mem | sed '1d' | awk -v threads="$i" 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print threads, $1, $2}' | tee -a cluster_resources.txt`. I gave the accepted answer to the "New contributor", I guess the # is mistyping or so. :))

Comment: @Tiina Good on you for giving them a boost.    The "#" is likely them wanting to output to the screen to test and neglecting to remove it afterwards to write to disk.  The bug is the -p "$aaa" which really should be corrected if this answer is to be accepted.

Comment: In her question, Tiina was not very clear what she wanted to with the "aaa" thing. So I assumed that she wants to get the stats of the processes whose IDs are 1 through 31. Defined like that, my script was tested, and it works. Anyway, I felt that she just needed to be pointed in the right direction, and she'd figure it out herself.

Comment: The "#" was intentionally left for her. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution - I believe this is slightly more elegant (and importantly I tested it (briefly) to make sure it actually works.

```
#! /bin/bash

# This allows you to specify the PID you are interested in at the command prompt, as I expect hard coding is not a good idea.

if [ "$1." == "." ]
then
    echo Usage: $0 pid
    exit 1
fi

for each in {1..31}
do
    echo ${each}$(ps -p $1 --noheaders -o %cpu,%mem| tr -s ' ' ',') >> /tmp/file.name
done
```

Comment: The "tr" translates characters - in this case converting space to comma.  The -s removes duplicates of the character being replaced.  This is a lot simpler then AWK.    Likewise $1 is the first argument on the command line.

Comment: When you say your elegant solution "actually works", you imply mine doesn't?  :-)

Comment: @pourko Yes. Monitoring pid 1-31 is not a sensible thing to do as most of those pids won't exist after boot. Similarly the question specified a PID 31690 again making that interpretation non-valid.  I also upvoted your answer because it is largely along the lines I was thinking.  (Also, its better to get clarification then write a wrong answer as this is a knowledge repo for future reference- I agree the original question could gave been clearer.

Comment: Dude, I was just kidding. Her request was not exactly clear. And yes, I could have never come up with your solution. It's all good! :-))